# Userform giving Run Time error 91 when selecting a range in a sheet and multiplying with a number

Tags: excel, vba

I have userform which will help me to calculate the currency exchange rate. 
It has two RefEditBox (RefEdit1 = Input Range, RefEdit2 = Output Range) One textbox(TextBox1 - To enter the currency rate) Tow Command Button (CommandButton2 = Go and CommandButton1 = Cancel)

[image]

I basically want that from RefEdit1, I should select the Input range (cells for which I want to calculate the currency exchange rate value), 
TextBox1, I can enter the Currency exchange rate
RefEdit2 is my output range where I want the exchange rates value to reflect.

So basically each cells from the input range should be multiplied with the TextBox1 value and should give the output on the range specified in the RefEdit2.

I have created this code, however it is giving me error

> Run Time error 91 Object variable or with block variable not set

on this line :

```
rng = ws.Range(Me.RefEdit1.Text)
```

Please find below the code:

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
   Unload UserForm1
End Sub

Private Sub CommandButton2_Click()

Dim ws As Worksheet

Dim rng As Range

ws = ActiveWorkbook.ActiveSheet

rng = ws.Range(Me.RefEdit1.Text)

rng.Formula = Application.Evaluate("=" & rng.Address & "*" & Me.TextBox1.Value)

Range(Me.RefEdit2.Text) = rng.Value


End Sub
```

Comment: you need to set the range `rng` to a range first (like: `set rng = Worksheets("sheet1").Range("A1")`. before you can use it.

Comment: Guessing that you need `Set rng = Range(Me.RefEdit1.Text) \\
    rng.Formula = Application.Evaluate("=" & rng.Address & "*" & Me.TextBox1.Value) \\
    Range(Me.RefEdit2.Text) = rng.Value`

Comment: Hi I have revised the code as below but still giving error

Comment: You forgot the `Set`.

Comment: this code is working but now what is happening is that it is also changing values of the input range as well, please suggest how to control it as I want that Input range should only be the reference point and the output range is the range where I want the output

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are treating the two ranges as one, and that's why both are being affected. The following separates those out and does the trick:

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()

   Unload UserForm1

End Sub

Private Sub CommandButton2_Click()

    'Declare
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim inputrng As Range
    Dim outputrng As Range

    'Set
    Set ws = ActiveWorkbook.ActiveSheet
    Set inputrng = ws.Range(Me.RefEdit1.Text)
    Set outputrng = ws.Range(Me.RefEdit2.Text)

    'Write calculated value
    outputrng.Formula = Application.Evaluate("=" & inputrng.Address & "*" & Me.TextBox1.Value)

    'Undeclare
    Set ws = Nothing
    Set inputrng = Nothing
    Set outputrng = Nothing

End Sub
```